# Why infix operators lose their fixities in let/do bindings

Tags: haskell

I defined a low precedence (lowMult) infix operators like this :

```
a `lowMult` b = a*b  
infix 1 `lowMult`
```

So that GHCi evaluates `` 8-1 `lowMult` 4 + 2 `` to `42`
However, in a list comprehension like :  `` [8 - 1 `op` 4 + 2 | op <- [lowMult]] ``, the operators (`op`) seems to have the `(*)` fixity, as GHCi evaluates the previous list comprehension to `[6]`

Comment: You seem to have two functions: `lowMult` and `lowM`.

Comment: Yes, I first named it lowM but function with capital M at the end are exclusively for monadic functions, I didn't make all the changes, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Haskell, fixities are defined per *name*. So if you define a new name for an operator, that name will have its own fixity--different from the original.

In your list comprehension, you define a new name for `lowMult`--`op`. Since you do not specify `op`'s fixity, it gets the default level, which is the highest possible fixity with left associativity. This makes it bind even *tighter* than multiplication.

This behavior is really the only logical choice. What would you do in this scenario, otherwise?

```
[8 - 1 `op` 4 + 2 | op <- [lowMult, (*)]]
```

What if the operators were passed in as arguments, or results of more complicated expressions themselves? The fixity of all the operators has to be defined at compile-time, so it can't depend on runtime information like this.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, it was just an attempt to generate all arithmetic expressions of the form a.b.c.d with . in (*,-,+,/) and with parenthesis